# How is a differentiator op-amp current possible?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, current

I have been reading about op amps and came across this description of a differentiator variant using a capacitor.

[image]

The author explains that current can go through the capacitor when there is changing voltage, but I struggle to understand how the capacitor does not block the DC voltage source. Could anybody explain how there can be current in this situation?

[Full link to article](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-8/differentiator-integrator-circuits/)

Comment: The current through a cap is equal to the differential of the voltage, in other words, the change in voltage. This does not apply to DC, as this is not changing.

Comment: That's because it DOES block the DC voltage source. However if the "DC" voltage changes (meaning it's not perfect DC) it'll allow that change through. And ... that includes whatever happens when you first switch on.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But can DC voltage not vary without being AC? My understanding is you can have variable DC voltage, for example as a result of a measuring instrument of some sort. If so, how would the differentiator work with a DC source?

Comment: To correct a misapprehension, current does NOT flow **through** a capacitor - the dielectric is an insulator that we normally assume to be ideal. If a current flows **into** one plate of a capacitor, the equivalent current must flow **out of** the other plate. The transfer of charge is through the current or voltage source, not through the capacitor.

Comment: ... in your circuit, if the input voltage is varying, the charge on the capacitor is varying, and hence there must be a varying current. This current flows through \$\small R\$, and so the op amp output voltage varies. Note that if the input voltage is constant, the current will be zero and the op amp output voltage will be zero (derivative of a constant = 0). In this sense the capacitor is 'blocking DC'.

Comment: Variation in DC IS an AC component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The author explains that current can go through the capacitor when
> there is changing voltage*

That's pretty much the definition of a circuit that acts like a differentiator.

> *but I struggle to understand how the capacitor does not block the DC
> voltage source.*

It **does** block DC - that's the whole point of a differentiator - DC is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But can DC voltage not vary without being AC? My understanding is you can have variable DC voltage, for example as a result of a measuring instrument of some sort. If so, how would the differentiator work with a DC source?

Comment: DC voltage that varies can be directly equated as a constant DC voltage (an offset) with a superimposed AC voltage @ZhelyazkoGrudov

Comment: So you're saying that the not changing part is getting blocked, and only the change is going through, which would be the only way for current to go through a capacitor, right?

Comment: I am saying that @ZhelyazkoGrudov - I guess you may not have been familiar with the usage of the term DC here - EE's will use that term for power supplies AND they will use that term for a constant voltage. Sometimes we forget how we use terms and I can see that would have confused you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

> when there is changing voltage

means: not constant voltage.

DC is constant voltage. And that's blocked, as you've noticed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But can DC voltage not vary without being AC? My understanding is you can have variable DC voltage, for example as a result of a measuring instrument of some sort. If so, how would the differentiator work with a DC source?